# How to put an Entity Framework query result into a List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0

How to Put the following query result into a List

```
var  result = from c in sb.Swithches_SW_PanalComponents
                     select new { c.ID,c.SW_PanalComponents.ComponentsName,c.ComponentValue };
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` has an `ToList` extension method. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**FINAL EDIT**

Based on your last comment, this is all you ever needed

```
List<Swithches_SW_PanalComponents> result = 
                                  sb.Swithches_SW_PanalComponents.ToList();
```

which of course is identical to

```
var result = sb.Swithches_SW_PanalComponents.ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, I think this is what you want:

```
List<SW_PanalComponents> result = sb.Swithches_SW_PanalComponents
                  .Select(c => new SW_PanalComponents { /* initialize your fields */ })
                  .ToList();
```

**END EDIT**

The `ToList` method is what you want.  But consider using dot notation.  For simple queries like this, it's much cleaner and trimmer.

```
var result = sb.Swithches_SW_PanalComponents
                  .Select(c => new { c.ID, c.SW_PanalComponents.ComponentsName, c.ComponentValue })
                  .ToList();
```

Also note that, if you're just trying to execute your query immediately, and only need to enumerate over it, you can also call `AsEnumerable()`

```
var result = sb.Swithches_SW_PanalComponents
                  .Select(c => new { c.ID, c.SW_PanalComponents.ComponentsName, c.ComponentValue })
                  .AsEnumerable();
```

The advantage here is that result is a less specific type—`IEnumerablt<T>`.

Comment: @desaivv - unless I'm doing a join, I almost never use query syntax.

Comment: I want to put the result stored in the **Var result** into a List<T> variable

Comment: @major - well if you want it as a `List<T>` then ToList() will work.  I'm just saying it's usually a good idea to code against the least specific type—ie IEnumerable instead of List

Comment: what i want is to be able to write the following code 
'List<SW_PanalComponents> MyList = new List<SW_PanalComponents>();'
'MyList=result; //with some method to convert the **result** to a **List<T>** ' 
the reason i want to do this is i want to add items and remove items from the list and use the add() and remove() methods of the list.

Comment: @major - ok, then ToList like Icarus and I have will do that

Comment: @Adam Rackis - thanks for help, but lcarus answer still have the result as a Var object, i wonder how can i use the add() method to add an entity object to that var result, i am afraid that i am missing something of your answers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6568/discussion-between-major-and-adam-rackis)

Comment: finaly it worked this way
` List<Swithches_SW_PanalComponents> MyList = new List<Swithches_SW_PanalComponents>();
            var Result = from all in sb.Swithches_SW_PanalComponents
                         select all
                         ;
            MyList.AddRange(Result.ToList<Swithches_SW_PanalComponents>());`

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
var  result =(from c in sb.Swithches_SW_PanalComponents
                     select new 
                     { c.ID,
                       c.SW_PanalComponents.ComponentsName,
                       c.ComponentValue 
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Make sure your reference System.Linq.

Answer (score 0):

That what i came with finally:

```
  List<Swithches_SW_PanalComponents> MyList = new List<Swithches_SW_PanalComponents>();
        var Result = from all in sb.Swithches_SW_PanalComponents
                     select all
                     ;
        MyList.AddRange(Result.ToList<Swithches_SW_PanalComponents>());
```